# Storing Session Variables in Lift Scala

Tags: session, scala, variables, lift

I am trying to store a session variable and then use it to modify the menu in Boot.scala.  Here is how I am storing the variable in a snippet:

```
object sessionUserType extends  SessionVar[String](null)
  def list (xhtml : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {

    Helpers.bind("sendTo", xhtml, 
                 "provider" -> SHtml.link("/providerlogin",() => sessionUserType("provider"), Text("Provider")),
                 "student" -> SHtml.link("/studentlogin",() => sessionUserType("student"), Text("Student")))
    }
```

Then in Boot.scala I do this:

```
val studentSessionType = If(() => S.getSessionAttribute("sessionUserType").open_!.equals("student"),
            "not a student session")
```

I also tried to call the object by name (sessionUserType), but it can never find it, so I thought this might work, but I keep getting an empty box when i access it even though the actual binding and function get executed prior to the menu rendering.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to get a value from `SessionVar` or `RequestVar`, call `is` method on it, i.e. `sessionUserType.is`

By the way, did you read "[Managing State](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Managing_State)"?

### Side note

I believe `RequestVar` is a better fit in your case. I am not sure I could catch your code right without the context, but it could be rewritten at least like:

```
case class LoginType
case object StudentLogin extends LoginType
case object ProviderLogin extends LoginType

object loginType extends RequestVar[Box[LoginType]](Empty)
// RequestVar is a storage with request-level scope

...
"provider" -> SHtml.link("/providerlogin",() => loginType(Full(ProviderLogin)), Text("Provider")),
// `SHtml.link` works in this way. Your closure will be called after a user
// transition, that is when /providerlogin is loading.
...

val studentSessionType = If(() => { loginType.is map {_ == StudentLogin} openOr false },
                "not a student session")
// As a result, this test will be true if our RequestVar holds StudentLogin,
// but it will be so for one page only (/studentlogin I guess). If you want
// scope to be session-wide, use SessionVar
```

Comment: Alexander-

Thanks for this.  Unfortunately, I think I need to use a SessionVar as I will be modifying the menu and the view accordingly throughout the user's session depending on what type of user they are.  The problem I am having is when I try to access the SessionVar, say StudentLogin in Boot.scala, the compiler can't find it.  That is why I resorted to using the S object in the first place.  Is there some trick (outside of importing the class, which I've tried) to get the SessionVar which is in snippets.LoginType (for instance) within the scope of Boot.scala?  

Thanks

Comment: I think I've got it.  The object needed to be outside of the class definition of the snippet.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Lift creates snippet instances, so any object declared in the snippet class will live as long as snippet instances lives, which is not what you want for session-scope storage.

Comment: Is there a default place to declare all session variables?  Like Boot.scala?  And if so, will other snippets, models, etc, be able access them just by calling VariableName...?

Comment: You can declare them on the top level (package) or in an object if appropriate

Comment: BTW Your link to "About Session State" is just a blank page.

Comment: @drozzy Lift documentation moved from Github pages to Assembla. I've fixed the link. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the disconnect is that you are assuming that the a *Session Attribute* is going to match your *SessionVar*, and that is not the case.  Lift is a very [secure](http://wiki.github.com/dpp/liftweb/lifts-security) framework, and one if its features is that Lift creates opaque GUIDs to refer to components on the
server side.

If you want `getSessionAttribute` to return something, think about how you can call `setSessionAttribute`.